# how to left align the whole document starting from first heading?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\underline{TCS-505}\\
\underline{DAA TUT-1}
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{Name:Megha Saraswat}\\
\textbf{Sec: Purple}\\
\textbf{Roll No: 65}
\end{flushright}
\underline{I.Logarithm Properties:-}
\[1.\log_{a}x^{k}=k\log_{a}x\]
\[2.\log_{a}(mn)=\log_{a}m+\log_{a}n\]
\[3.\log_{a}(m/n)=\log_{a}m-\log_{a}n\]
\[4.\log_{a}x=\frac{1}{\log_{x}a}=\frac{\log_{b}x}{\log_{b}a}\]
\[5.x^{\log_{a}y}=y^{\log_{a}x}\]
\underline{II.Exponential Properties:-}
\[1.\left( a^{m}\right) ^{n}=a^{mn}\]
\[2.a^{m}a^{n}=a^{m+n}\]
\[3.\frac{a^{m}}{a^{n}}=a^{m-n}\]
\[4.\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^{b}}{a^{n}}=0\]
\underline{III.Series:-}
\[1.\;1+2+3---------+n=\frac{n\left( n+1\right) }{2}\]
\[2.\;1^{2}+2^{2}+3^{2}+---------+n^{2}=\frac{n\left( n+1\right) \left( 2n+1\right) }{6}\]
\[3.\;1^{3}+2^{3}+3^{3}+---------+n^{3}=\frac{n^{2}\left( n+1\right)^{2}}{4}\]
\[4.\;1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+---------+x^{k-1}=\frac{x^{k}-1}{x-1}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436) Could you expand a bit on what you're asking?  (Also, if I may, you might also want to learn a bit more about the concepts of TeX systems; you've turned it into a run-of-the-mill word processor, doing things manually where you should be letting TeX make decisions.)

Comment: I don't think this is what you're asking, but following LaTeX-y conventions produces a very nice result (which can be customized *without* altering anything between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.  See http://pastebin.com/i94GHC6v which produces the following: http://i.stack.imgur.com/U5vHn.png

Comment: I think you should have a look to [lshort.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort).

Comment: Hello, is there anybody in there? Just nod if you can hear me, is there anyone at home? `:)`

Answer (score 2):

In terms of left-alignment and noticing your manual enumeration, you might be after something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\setlist[enumerate]{labelindent=0pt,leftmargin=*}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \underline{TCS-505} \\
  \underline{DAA TUT-1}
\end{center}

\begin{flushright}\bfseries
  Name: Megha Saraswat \\
  Sec: Purple \\
  Roll No: 65
\end{flushright}

\underline{\strut I.~Logarithm Properties:}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $\log_{a}x^{k} = k\log_{a}x$
  \item $\log_{a}(mn) = \log_{a}m + \log_{a}n$
  \item $\log_{a}(m/n) = \log_{a}m - \log_{a}n$
  \item $\log_{a}x = \frac{1}{\log_{x}a} = \frac{\log_{b}x}{\log_{b}a}$
  \item $x^{\log_{a}y} = y^{\log_{a}x}$
\end{enumerate}

\underline{\strut II.~Exponential Properties:}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $\left( a^{m}\right)^{n} = a^{mn}$
  \item $a^{m}a^{n} = a^{m+n}$
  \item $\frac{a^{m}}{a^{n}} = a^{m-n}$
  \item $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^{b}}{a^{n}} = 0$
\end{enumerate}

\underline{\strut III.~Series:}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $1+2+3+\cdots+n = \frac{n\left( n+1\right) }{2}$
  \item $1^{2}+2^{2}+3^{2}+\cdots+n^{2} = \frac{n\left( n+1\right) \left( 2n+1\right) }{6}$
  \item $1^{3}+2^{3}+3^{3}+\cdots+n^{3} = \frac{n^{2}\left( n+1\right)^{2}}{4}$
  \item $1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+\cdots+x^{k-1} = \frac{x^{k}-1}{x-1}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

A `\strut` was introduced with each "section" to obtain a consistent baseline rule. Also, it would be possible to automate the use of sections and their formatting, but I'm not sure how big your scope is.

Left-alignment of the enumeration is obtain through [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `labelindent=0pt` and `leftmargin=*` options (set globally), as well as a `0pt` paragraph indent (`\parindent`, also set globally).

Comment: I deleted my answer because it is almost the same, but I want suggest avoid underlines and use automatically numbered sections as suggest Werner. Just test with `\renewcommand \thesection{\Roman{section}.}` in the preamble and section as `\section{Logarithm Properties:}`.

Comment: Also, as a note to OP, you can make the math bigger/prettier by inserting a `\displaystyle` at the beginning of each equation when using inline math (`$...$`).  Best of both worlds, in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Equations can also be left aligned with option `fleqn`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\setlength{\mathindent}{.5\mathindent}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \uline{TCS-505}\\
  \uline{DAA TUT-1}
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
    Name:& Megha Saraswat\\
    Sec:& Purple\\
    Roll No:& 65
  \end{tabular}%
\end{flushright}
\uline{I. Logarithm Properties:}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \[\log_{a}x^{k}=k\log_{a}x\]
  \item \[\log_{a}(mn)=\log_{a}m+\log_{a}n\] 
  \item \[\log_{a}(m/n)=\log_{a}m-\log_{a}n\]
  \item \[\log_{a}x=\frac{1}{\log_{x}a}=\frac{\log_{b}x}{\log_{b}a}\]
  \item \[x^{\log_{a}y}=y^{\log_{a}x}\]
\end{enumerate}
\uline{II. Exponential Properties:}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \[\left( a^{m}\right) ^{n}=a^{mn}\]
  \item \[a^{m}a^{n}=a^{m+n}\]
  \item \[\frac{a^{m}}{a^{n}}=a^{m-n}\]
  \item \[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^{b}}{a^{n}}=0\]
\end{enumerate}
\uline{III. Series:}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \[1+2+3+\cdots+n=\frac{n\left( n+1\right) }{2}\]
  \item \[1^{2}+2^{2}+3^{2}+\cdots+n^{2}=\frac{n\left( n+1\right)
          \left(2n+1\right) }{6}\]
  \item \[1^{3}+2^{3}+3^{3}+\cdots+n^{3}=\frac{n^{2}
          \left(n+1\right)^{2}}{4}\]
  \item \[1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+\cdots+x^{k-1}=\frac{x^{k}-1}{x-1}\]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The indentation of the equations can be configured with length `\mathindent`.
- `\uline` is used for underlining with package `ulem`.
- The equations are enumerated via environment `enumerate`.
- A `tabular` is used for the name fields.